# How can I get dll registry information and write it into msi registry table

Tags: dll, installation, windows-installer

I have some dll files that should be assembled and registered into a msi file. I want to read the relative information from the dll file and write these items into msi file directly. But how can I read these registry information from dll file? What information should I write into msi registry table? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What tool are you using to create your MSI?

Comment: You cannot usually read them from the DLL.  You could use SysInternals' ProcMon and observe which keys get written when you register the DLL.  If you don't control the source of this DLL then this might not be the greatest idea, you'll need to keep carefully track of updates so you can tweak your table as needed.  Do favor using the vendor's installer.

Comment: @Hans- Yes you can.  I know of several tools that will perform COM extraction / harvesting and author it into your installer.  I can't make the best suggestion without knowing what tool he is using.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of commercial setup authoring tools can extract the DLL registration information. For example, you can try [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/).

Another approach is to register your DLLs manually with the appropriate command line tool. Using an installation repackager, you can capture this process into an MSI. This way you can catch all the registry entries created by the registration process.